# Unwanted display of 180 meridian in map

Tags: qgis, antimeridian

When I use the WGS 84 CRS the Chukotka peninsula east of the 180 meridian is shown on the left of the map. If I project (on-the-fly) the map using a Lambert Azimuth projection, the Chukotka peninsula is shown as a whole, but the 180 meridian is shown as a line through the peninsula.

Can someone please tell me how I can either:

- project my map so that the 180 meridian is not shown, or
- tell me how I can hide the meridian in the vector layer, or
- merge the two polygons (there does not seem to be a Merge option in QGIS, unlike ArcGIS)

The syntax I am using is:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=55 +lon_0=40 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

I am using QGIS 2.14.1 on Windows 10.

[image: 180 meridian displayed in map]

Comment: can you add a screen shot or a link to one so we can see what you mean

Comment: Wow! Andre blocks my question and refers me to another post because of duplication (fair enough) so I post my question there. Then Kersten blocks my question there because it doesn't ANSWER that question. Uh?

Comment: that is because the duplicate question has an answer that solves your problem. please take the (tour)[https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour] if the process is unclear